# Why if I request more than 100 rows to my database on the server do I get nothing as a result?

Tags: php, android, json, post, outputstream

I'm trying to receive an entire table of data from my server to my App. This function I need only at the first access to be able to load an allocated table on the device and in the future update it dynamically with new data.
The problem I encountered is that the table is made up of 600 rows and when from my php file I generate the json in the answer reader on Android it is empty.I tried to find a way to receive an entire table but I could not solve, I hope you managed to help me.

If I reduce the value of rows to 100 I have no problem, but I can't send them all, I wanted to know if there is another way to be able to receive whole tables or larger files.

This is my class in the applocation that makes the call to the server and php file to extract the table:

```
 private String makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific(String languageTOpass, String urlAdress) {
    String responce=null;
    Log.v(TAG, "GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific : SEND MY REQUEST....");
 tringBuffer data_post = new StringBuffer();
try {
        data_post.append(URLEncoder.encode("Language","UTF-8"));
        data_post.append("=");
        data_post.append(URLEncoder.encode(languageTOpass,"UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    String json = "";
    InputStream responseStream = null;
    String logMess = "";
    long startTime;
    long stopTime;
    long elapsedTime;

    try {

        byte[] postDataBytes = data_post.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        JSONObject Language_Json = new JSONObject();
        Language_Json.put("Language",languageTOpass);

        String Message_send = Language_Json.toString();
        Log.v(TAG, "GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific : IL VALORE DI Message_send...." + Message_send);
     URL url = new URL(urlAdress);

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    conn.setUseCaches(true);
    conn.connect();

    OutputStreamWriter request = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    request.write(Message_send);
    request.flush();
    request.close();

        
        InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) conn.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        Log.d(TAG, "GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: IL VALORE DI READR--- " + reader.toString());
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        Log.d(TAG, "GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: IL VALORE DI RESULT--- " + result.toString());
        String line;
        
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: SONO NEL CICLO DI SCRITTURA DELLA RISPOSTA--- " + conn);
            result.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        json = result.toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: ************************************************************ " );
        Log.d(TAG, "GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: ************************************************************ " );
        Log.d(TAG, "GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: THE DIMENSION OF THE RECEPTION : " + json.getBytes().length);
        Log.d(TAG, "GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: ************************************************************ " );
        Log.d(TAG, "GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: ************************************************************ " );
        Log.d(TAG, "GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: ************************************************************ " );
        Log.d(TAG, "GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: RESOULT : " + json);

        conn.disconnect();

        Log.d(TAG, "GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: Connection --- " + conn);

    } catch (IOException | JSONException e ) {
        Log.e(TAG, "GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific:ERROR MESSAGE --- " + e.getMessage());
        Log.e(TAG, "GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific:ERROR MESSAGE Cause --- " + e.getCause());
    }
    return json;
}
```

This is the php file where I generate the json file on the server to send to my app:

```
<? php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$host ='localhost';
$username ='***';
$pwd ='**';
$db ='MYDB';
$responce =array();
$responce ["success"]= 0 ;
$responce ["message"]= "Error at start";
$json=file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj_json=json_decode($json,TRUE);
if(isset($obj_json)){
   $language=$obj_json['Language'];
   $connect = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$pwd,$db) or die('Unabletp connect');
   if(mysqli_connect_error($connect)){
    echo ("Fallita la connessione al data base".mysqli_connect_error());
    $responce ['success']=0;
    $responce ['message']="NO CONNECTION  NEW_SPECIFIC_PRODUCT";
}else{
        // I SET MY SEARCH QUERY
        // CHECK THAT THE LANGUAGE IS ITALIAN
        if(strcasecmp($language,"it")== 0){
            $sql_find = ("SELECT FAMILY_PRODUCT,CATEGORY_PRODUCT,SPECIFIC_PRODUCT,NAME_SPECIFIC FROM NEW_SPECIFIC_PRODUCT_IT;") ;
            $result= mysqli_query($connect,$sql_find) or  die ("Error: ". mysqli_error($connect)." with query ");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)> 0){
                $responce ["success"]= 1 ;
                $i=0;
                
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                
                    $name_specific=$row["NAME_SPECIFIC"];
                    $result_array[$i]= array("FAMILY_PRODUCT" => $row["FAMILY_PRODUCT"],"CATEGORY_PRODUCT"  =>$row["CATEGORY_PRODUCT"],"SPECIFIC_PRODUCT" => $row["SPECIFIC_PRODUCT"],"NAME_SPECIFIC" => $name_specific);
                    $i++;
                }
                
                $responce ['success']=1;
                $responce ['message']="I VALORI SONO STATI TROVATI";
                
                }else{
                # code...
                $responce ['success']=0;
                $responce ['message']="NO DATA IN  NEW_SPECIFIC_PRODUCT_IT";
            }
        }else{
            // THE TELEPHONE LANGUAGE IS NOT ITALIAN
            echo ("IL VALORE DI language non è it.....".$language);
            $sql_find = ("SELECT * FROM NEW_SPECIFIC_PRODUCT_EN;") ;
            $result= mysqli_query($connect,$sql_find) or  die ("Error: ". mysqli_error($connect)." with query ");
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)> 0){
                $responce ["success"]= 1 ;
                $i=0;
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    $result_array[$i]= array("FAMILY_PRODUCT" =>$row["FAMILY_PRODUCT"],"CATEGORY_PRODUCT"=>$row["CATEGORY_PRODUCT"],"SPECIFIC_PRODUCT"=>$row["SPECIFIC_PRODUCT"],"NAME_SPECIFIC"=>$row["NAME_SPECIFIC"]);
                    $i++;
                }
                
            }else{
                # code...
                $responce ['success']=0;
                $responce ['message']="NO DATA IN  NEW_SPECIFIC_PRODUCT_EN";
            }
        }           
mysqli_close($connect);
array_push($responce,$result_array);
}
}else{
   $responce['success']=0;
   $responce['message']="Parameters are not correct";
echo json_encode($responce);
 }
header('Content-type:application/json');
echo json_encode($responce);
   ?>
```

When I go to verify my sent json the result is empty and when I don't receive anything, is there another method to be able to receive an entire table?
Thanks in advance for the help.

I add the log files as required:

```
GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: IL VALORE DI READR--- java.io.BufferedReader@---
GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: IL VALORE DI RESULT--- 
GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: ************************************************************ 
GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: ************************************************************ 
GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: LA DIMENSIONE DELLA RICEZIONE : 0
GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: ************************************************************
```

Comment: `Log.d(TAG, "GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: IL VALORE DI READR--- " + reader.toString()); ` What should reader.toString() deliver? Please tell what is logged.
 `

Comment: I added the log files, but I don't understand why you had to put a negative score on my question right away?

Comment: `Log.d(TAG, "GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: IL VALORE DI RESULT--- " + result.toString());
` That makes no sense there as there is nothing in the string builder yet. Please move statement to after while loop. Please report.

Comment: And why didnt you tell us what is logged by: `Log.d(TAG, "GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: SONO NEL CICLO DI SCRITTURA DELLA RISPOSTA--- " + conn);
` ? And conn? Typo? That should be line. It looks as if no single line is read. Please investigate. This is elementary. Basic debugging.

Comment: 'GetSpecificListFromServer: makeHttpRequestJsonListSpecific: IL VALORE DI RESULT--- ' I moved as you said and the result is this, Always empty

Comment: Well ... if you cannot read lines... if there are no lines... then why talking about json? Or anything after that while loop?

Comment: `If I reduce the value of rows to 100 I have no problem,` Well that is very strange. No reason for that would say. (You could have posted that as first line of your post as i only saw it now . You could give it more attention!!! How do i ask...... What is my problem...

Comment: YES conn is a typo, and I corrected it but the value it returns me is the link to my php file on my server and if I click it gives me result '{"success": 0, "message": "Parameters are not correct "} {" success ": 0," message ":" Parameters are not correct "} 'but this value also gives it to me when I get the correct json.

Comment: Thanks for the advice now I move it to the beginning of my question

Comment: In fact this was my question, why if I reduce the size no problem, while the whole table instead gives me 0 as the string value? I thought it was a size problem

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for the advice I corrected the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to the problem and report it so that if it is useful to someone, they can use it.
After multiple checks I noticed that the problem was that my Json was not created in my php file, so working with a part of my DB that was composed of String values I tried to check for Json generation errors by adding this code immediately mouse generation of the Json:

```
echo json_encode($responce);
switch (json_last_error()) {
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
        echo ' - No errors';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
        echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
        echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
    break;
    default:
        echo ' - Unknown error';
    break;
}
 echo PHP_EOL;
```

From this verification it turned out that my error was of type "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"
so I proceeded to insert a UTF-8 decoding after extracting the result of my Query and before inserting it in my answer array which I would then encode in Json.
This allowed me to create my Json correctly and overcome the block dictated by the particular characters that did not allow encoding.

```
$name_specific=utf8_encode($row["NAME_SPECIFIC"]);
```

I hope it can help someone who is in the same block as me, Thanks everyone.